# laravel task scheduler deleting a post

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I setup a simple task scheduler in laravel everything works only problem that i am having is that the post is not deleting at the time i set. I want the post to delete after 5 minutes since the post was created at, not sure why my posts are deleting after a minute.I believe i want my task scheduler to check after every minute because each post has a different delete time. here my scheduler:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{


    $schedule->call(function (){
    $post=    Post::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5))->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: you need change `everyMinute` to dinamyc for each post?

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos yah that what i need to do, so that each post deletes 5 minutes after from when the post was created.

Comment: `everyFiveMinutes();` this command is for execute you task 5 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it would look as though you should be subtracting the minutes, not adding them

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Post::where('created_at', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5))->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

If you are just using `Carbon::now()` make sure you import it with a use statement. If you use it like I have in this example you don't need to import it.

Also since you're not using the `$post` variable after delete, you do not need to assign it.

Comment: ok thank you @SimonR this was what i was looking for so the task runs every minute once the created_at reaches the carbon the post deletes